# How to add a progressive numeration for multiple artboards?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, automation, numbering

How to create a text frame with a progressive numbering that automatically increases in all the artboards? (as an automatic numbering of pages)

```
For example:
artboard 1 => number 100
artboard 2 => number 101
artboard 3 => number 102
etc
```

[image: example of the project]

I've already done it manually for another project, as shown in the screenshot, but I'd like to avoid the manually solution for this project. So I was trying to find another solution, not a manual one, keeping using Illustrator.

Comment: Illustrator has no automatic page numbering feature, although you may be able to script it, or there may be existing scripts out there. I think it would be better to use InDesign for creating a multi-page document since it's actually designed for page layout, and Illustrator isn't.  InDesign has automatic page numbering.

Comment: Thanks @BillyKerr for this project I have to use Illustrator, so I'm trying to look for the scripts but I haven't find them yet. Do you have any other advice for Illustrator with or without using the scripts?

Comment: Without a script, you'd probably need to do it manually I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested this script and does the job:

```
function test(){

var doc = app.activeDocument;

var startNum = prompt("Specify the starting index", "1");

if(startNum == null || !startNum){

return;

}

 startNum *= 1;

if(isNaN(startNum)){

alert("Not a valid number");

return;

}

var newText, thisRect;

var pageNumLayer = doc.layers.add();

pageNumLayer.name = "Page Numbers";

var counter = startNum;

for(var i = 0;  i < doc.artboards.length;  i++){

newText = pageNumLayer.textFrames.add();

newText.contents = counter++;

thisRect = doc.artboards[i].artboardRect;

newText.position = [thisRect[2] - 20, thisRect[3] + 20];

};

};

test();
```

[image: pages]

Source: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2395987

Comment: I tried the script and it works, but to set it up you need to know JavaScript first and above all the properties and methods used by Illustrator. The learning curve is quite high. I've followed these documents [pdf](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/illustrator/pdf/Illustrator_JavaScript_Scripting_Reference_2017.pdf) - [web](http://jongware.mit.edu/iljscs6html/iljscs6/index_Scripting%20commands%20and%20classes%20for%20Adobe%20Illustrator.html), but I haven't yet managed to modify the script as I wanted. Anyway, this is a step forward in the world of script for Ai. Thank you!

Comment: I also proposed a semi-automatic solution without the use of scripts :)

Answer (score 1):

I found this method fast enough without using scripts

---

**Create a new Document with multiple Artboards**

```
File > New... -> More Settings -> Number of Artboards
```

[image]

---

**Create a Area type in all Artboards**

`Type tool` : *drag diagonally to define a rectangular bounding area within the Artboards*

`Control panel` : *set the Font, Font Style and Size (The height of the character must be slightly smaller than the height of the Area type) options.*

`Selection tool` : *select the Area type object you just created*

```
Edit > Cut

Edit > Paste on All Artboards
```

---

**Link all the Area type objects**

`Selection tool` : *select all Area type objects*

```
Type > Threaded Text > Create
```

---

**With a spreadsheet program (Calc/Excel) create the numbering sequence**

Enter the first number in a cell, then click on that cell, so it has the black outline. Click on the little black square in the lower right corner of the outline, hold and drag down to the desired number.

[image]

Select all numbered cells and copy them.

---

**Enter the numbering in Illustrator**

`Selection tool` : *double click on the Area type object in the first Artboards*

```
Edit > Paste
```

---

For graphics, use a Symbol Instance inserted in all the Artboards in a layer below the Area type objects.

---

Instead I started to modify the [script](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/114749/112736) this way:

```
function bennytest(){

  var doc = app.activeDocument;

  function isNaNchecker(check) {
    if(check == null || !check){
      return;
    }

    // determines whether a value is an illegal number
    if(isNaN(check)){
      alert("Not a valid number");
      return;
    }
  }

  var startNum = prompt("Specify the starting index", "1");
  startNum *= 1;

  isNaNchecker(startNum);
  //alert(startNum + " - " + (typeof startNum));

  var marginBottomNum = prompt("Specify the bottom margin in pt", "0");
  marginBottomNum *= 1;

  isNaNchecker(marginBottomNum);
  // alert(marginBottomNum + " - " + (typeof marginBottomNum));

  var sizeNum = prompt("Specify the character dimension in pt", "20");
  sizeNum *= 1;

  isNaNchecker(sizeNum);
  // alert(sizeNum + " - " + (typeof sizeNum));

  var newText, thisRect;

  var pageNumLayer = doc.layers.add();

  pageNumLayer.name = "Auto-Numbers";

  var counter = startNum;

  // loop
  for(var i = 0;  i < doc.artboards.length;  i++){

    newText = pageNumLayer.textFrames.add();

    newText.contents = counter++;

    thisRect = doc.artboards[i].artboardRect;

    newText.position = [(thisRect[0] + thisRect[2]) / 2, thisRect[3] + marginBottomNum];
    // alert("0 (x0): " + thisRect[0] + "\n1 (y0): " + thisRect[1] + "\n2 (x1): " + thisRect[2] + "\n3 (y1): " + thisRect[3] + "\n\nw: " + newText.width + "\nh: " + newText.height);

    newText.textRange.characterAttributes.size = sizeNum;

    newText.textRange.justification = Justification.CENTER;

    // newText.textRange.characterAttributes.textFont = app.textFonts[7];      // who knows?
    // newText.textRange.characterAttributes.textFont.name = "Arial";          // doesn't work

  };

};

bennytest();
```

Comment: Well for non-coders & non-scripters, your workaround outlined above works like a champ!

Comment: @GerardFalla glad to read your comment, thank you :)

Comment: Awesome no script procedure! works amazing... thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just making it manually.

Once created an artboard with the text frame and duplicating it, you can create text threads like in Indesign and type the numbers:

[image: text]

Comment: Thanks @Danielillo but I'd like to avoid the manually solution for this project because there are a lot artboards